# powershell - possible to sort by string extracted from alllelements using custom property?

Tags: sorting, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I thought this would be a pretty simple undertaking - a program that returns webrequest elements and sorts them by a custom property which, in this case, is a substring "extracted" from $_.innertext. (Specifically, I want to sort a list of "deals" which are described in various ways by $-amount.)

But even simple string operations on $_.innertext don't seem to work, always yielding an error of this sort.

```
Sort-Object : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Here is the code I am working with - I'll appreciate any guidance, whether pointing out code issues or suggesting alternative methods.

```
# function to scrub text from a Class filtering on keyword, sort by $*
function Get-Deals {
    param($keyword)

    $url = "https://slickdeals.net/newsearch.php?q=$keyword"
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest $url
    $result.AllElements |
        Where Class -eq "dealTitle" | 
        Where {($_.innertext -match ($keyword)) -and ($_.innertext -match ("$"))} | 
        Sort-Object @{Expression={$_.inntertext.substring($_.innertext.IndexOf('$'))}} |
        Select -ExpandProperty innerText
        }

Get-Deals("TV")
```

Comment: Use `$_.innertext.IndexOf('$')` in the sort instead? Currently you're doing `$_.IndexOf`

Comment: thanks arco for pointing out that error. i think i introduced that error somewhere along the way. after making that change ISE give me this error: `Sort-Object : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` i have tried more simple method calls on $_.innertext -- e.g. `@{Expression={$_.inntertext.substring(0)` -- just to sort alphabetically and that does not work either. i wonder if you just cannot do this sort of this with simple string methods in powershell pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a (partial) solution to the problem I initially asked about. Code below - note these 2 changes:

1. $_.innertext enclosed in quotation marks in sort statement
2. some changes to Where criteria to make sure I was filtering adequately to ensure all elements have a '$' in them (previously I was missing some cases).

Here's why I said this is only a "(partial)" solution: Right now my sort is working, but I'm sorting based on strings, not by numbers. So $9.99 will come after $1999.99.

But that's an entirely different problem from what I initially asked about.

```
function Get-Deals {
param($keyword)
$url = "https://slickdeals.net/newsearch.php?q=$keyword"
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $url
$result.AllElements |
    Where Class -eq "dealTitle" | 
    Where {( ($_.innertext -match ($keyword)) -and ($_.innertext -like '*$*') )} |
    #Where {$_.innertext -like '*$*'} | 
    Sort-Object @{Expression={"$_.innertext".substring("$_.innertext".IndexOf('$'))}} |
    Select -ExpandProperty innerText
    }
Get-Deals("TV")
```